# How to start an mp4 file in python speech recognizer?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pyttsx3

I am creating a python voice assistant referring from a youtube tutorial. Unfortunately, the video creator has a windows os. So he uses startfile from OS module. But this is not working in ubuntu. Here is the code that the video maker used:

```
elif 'play music' in query:     
        music_dir = '/home/thilak/Music'
        songs = os.listdir(music_dir)
        print(songs)
        os.startfile(os.path.join(music_dir, songs[0]))
```

But this didn't work out for me, so I used this one:

```
elif 'play music' in query:     
        music_dir = '/home/thilak/Music'
        songs = os.listdir(music_dir)
        print(songs)
        os.system(os.path.join(music_dir, songs[0])) #changing startfile to system
```

Still, this code too shows an error message like this:

```
Say that again please...
Listening....
recognizing...
User said: play music

['Despacito and senorita (copy).mp4', 'Curtis Waters - Stunnin’ (Lyrics) “ I’m a pretty boy,I’m stunning “-YVrha4CjldA.mkv', 'DJ Snake ft. Justin Bieber - Let Me Love You [Lyric Video]-SMs0GnYze34 (copy).mkv', 'Curtis Waters - Stunnin’ (Lyrics) “ I’m a pretty boy,I’m stunning “-YVrha4CjldA (copy).mkv', 'Despacito and senorita.mp4', 'DJ Snake ft. Justin Bieber - Let Me Love You [Lyric Video]-SMs0GnYze34.mkv']
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Please help me resolve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: `sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected` -- search for that error. Nothing to do with Linux-specific APIs, Python or Ubuntu. In general, you also have to extract a [mcve] from your code for posting here. As a new user, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As given, the code was meant for windows, how about using `ffmpeg`'s `ffplay`

```py
elif 'play music' in query:     
        music_dir = '/home/thilak/Music'
        songs = os.listdir(music_dir)
        print(songs)
        os.popen('ffplay -nodisp -autoexit "'+os.path.join(music_dir, songs[0])+'" >/dev/null 2>&1')
```

before using the above codes do remember to install ffmpeg using apt

```sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Comment: Nope. I used this step, but there is still an error like:
"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: then i do not know any other library which could work on ubuntu

Comment: But thanks. It's okay. I got this step. I just need to fix that error.

Comment: try this please: `os.system(os.path.join(music_dir, songs[0]))` -> `os.system('"'+os.path.join(music_dir, songs[0])+'"')`

Comment: Awesome. That thing is now working. I mean segmentation error stopped. But I got another issue.
It tells like : permission denied.

Comment: I changed the folder permission settings too. But still that permission denied error continues.

Comment: wait , i will just write a new answer

Comment: please check now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226476/discussion-between-thilak-s-and-xcodz-dot).